# RxJS Multiple conditional calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem with conditional calls in RxJS.
 The scenario is that I have multiple HTTP-Calls inside a forkjoin. But inside the calls there can be dependencies, like I get a boolean back from first call and if that is true the second call should be fired.
This is my code right now:

```
 service.method(parameters).pipe(
  tap((data: boolean) => {
    foo.bar= data;
  }),
  concatMap(() =>
    service
      .method(parameters)
      .pipe(
        tap((data: KeyValue<number, string>[]) => {
          if (true) {
            foo.foo = data;
          }
        })
      )
  )
)
```

The problem that I have is that the method now always gets called. My goal is that the method only gets called when the parameter is true, to reduce the amount of calls. I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
service.method(parameters).pipe(
  tap((data: boolean) => {
    foo.bar= data;
  }),
  concatMap((data) => data ? // you pass data as parameter and check if true
    service  // if data is true you return the Observable returned by the service method
      .method(parameters)
      .pipe(
        tap((data: KeyValue<number, string>[]) => {
          if (true) {
            foo.foo = data;
          }
        })
      ) :
    of(false) // if data is false you return an Observable containing what you decide it to contain, in this case 'false' but it could be everything
  )
)
```

The idea is that you call the first time the `service.method`, pass the result of this call to `concatMap` and in there you decide, based on the parameter passed to `concatMap` whether to call again `service.method` and return the Observable it returns or return an Observable that you create within `concatMap` wrapping whatever value you want.

Comment: Wonderful, I have used it like 10 minutes after I posted this question, but it is good to see, that another person would do the same. Thank you for your answer!